# Accessing Controller instance from View in .net core 5

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-5.0

I've been accessing base controller instance from the view through following line, ASP.NET

```
BaseController baseController = ViewContext.Controller as BaseController;
```

I've new project in ASP.NET Core 5.0. I would like to access base controller for some reason, but it seems now it is not similar like previous version of MVC.

Is there any solution or alternative to achieve same?

NOTE: I want to access completely initialized instance of the controller. I tried to get instance through Dependency Injection using GetService() method. It gives new instance of controller, but not fully initialized, such as **HttpContext**, **User** etc properties are null.

Comment: how about you just send the controller base through the ViewModel from the controller to the View ? this way so save alot of processes casting and stuff

Comment: It’s probably worth noting that while [@King-King’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66691572/3025856) offers a solution to your question, it’s generally a code smell to need access to the controller from the view, and almost certainly violates the core design principles of the MVC pattern. A better solution is to take whatever information you need from your controller and inject it into the view model that you’re returning to your view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**NOTE:** this first solution based on `ControllerActionInvokerCache` is tested in `asp.net core 2.2` and worked fine. However in later versions, looks like that class is made `internal` and not accessible anymore, this solution will not help. Try the second solution introduced later.

The invoked controller is cached before in a `ControllerActionInvokerCache` (which is available via DI). The cache key is an instance of `ControllerContext` which is not equally compared by reference (so you can instantiate a new instance as long as the wrapped `ActionContext` is the current one). Actually `ControllerActionInvokerCache` is a composite cache.

You can see the code below for detail:

```
public static class RazorViewExtensions
{
    public static Controller GetInvokedController(this RazorPage view)
    {
        var serviceProvider = view.Context.RequestServices;
        var controllerCache = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ControllerActionInvokerCache>();         
        //ViewContext here is also an ActionContext   
        var controllerContext = new ControllerContext(view.ViewContext);
        var cacheEntry = controllerCache.GetCachedResult(controllerContext).cacheEntry;
        return cacheEntry == null ? null : cacheEntry.ControllerFactory(controllerContext) as Controller;
    }
}
```

For convenience, we declare an extension method as above. To use it inside your controller's view:

```
var controller = this.GetInvokedController();
```

You can base on that to write a similar extension method for using inside a Razor Page (the base page is `Page` instead of `RazorPage`).

Actually the `ControllerActionInvokerCacheEntry` is passed through to `ControllerActionDescriptor.CacheEntry`. However that `CacheEntry` property is internal (and of course not documented). We can see that in the source code. So basically you can use `reflection` to obtain that cache entry. However it requires reflection so the code block is even longer than the first solution we use above.

Here's another solution by extracting the controller instance from the `ActionExecutingContext.Controller`. This may be ***a little bit*** faster than the first solution but we need a separate class for the custom `IActionFilter` to capture the controller instance into a feature shared via `HttpContext.Features`. The code is of course a bit longer, like this:

```
//define the feature types
public interface IInvokedControllerFeature
{
    Controller Controller { get; }
}
public class InvokedControllerFeature : IInvokedControllerFeature
{
    public InvokedControllerFeature(Controller controller)
    {
        Controller = controller;
    }
    public Controller Controller { get; }
}

//an extension class to contain several convenient extension methods
//to setup the feature and get the controller instance later
public static class InvokedControllerFeatureExtensions
{
    public static Controller GetInvokedController(this HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        return httpContext.Features.Get<IInvokedControllerFeature>()?.Controller;
    }
    public static Controller GetInvokedController(this RazorPage view)
    {
        return view.Context.GetInvokedController();
    }
    public static IServiceCollection AddInvokedControllerFeature(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        return services.Configure<MvcOptions>(o => {
            o.Filters.Add<InvokedControllerFeatureActionFilter>();
        });
    }
    class InvokedControllerFeatureActionFilter : IActionFilter
    {
        public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context) {}

        public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            //share the controller instance via a feature
            context.HttpContext.Features.Set<IInvokedControllerFeature>(new InvokedControllerFeature(context.Controller as Controller));
        }
    }
}

//register the feature inside Startup.ConfigureServices
services.AddInvokedControllerFeature();
```

The usage inside a controller's view is just the same as in the first solution.

Comment: This 1st part, Razor View extension, (public static Controller GetInvokedController(this RazorPage view)) did not work, but later worked.
Thank you so much

Comment: @AftabAhmedKalhoro you're welcome, actually I've tested both solutions and both worked on my side. Could you share more info about how it's not working for the first solution? is there any exception or simply you get a `null` instance of the controller?

Comment: @AftabAhmedKalhoro I believe the error you had with the first solution is related to the `IActionContextAccessor` which is not registered on your side, however I've just found out that `ViewContext` is also an `ActionContext`, so we can conveniently use that instead of using an `IActionContextAccessor`, it shortens the code as well :)

Comment: There were errors:
ControllerActionInvokerCache is inaccessible due to its protection level

'ControllerActionInvokerCache.GetCachedResult(ControllerContext)' is inaccessible due to its protection level

'ControllerActionInvokerCacheEntry.ControllerFactory' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: @AftabAhmedKalhoro thank you for your response, looks like it's changed to `internal` in later versions of `asp.net core`, what I've tested is in `asp.net core 2.2`. I'll update the answer to reflect that.

Comment: as I've mentioned, I am using .NET Core 5.0. So possibly framework is changed. Anyway, thanks a lot for your support.

Comment: I am aslo wondered when I use var controller = this.GetInvokedController() as BaseController; i still get instance of Controller (i.e. HomeController) not BaseController

Comment: @AftabAhmedKalhoro your actual controller class inherits from `BaseController` so it should inherit all public & protected members of that base controller. You can access all public members of `BaseController` via the controller instance you get, so that should work. In other words, the controller instance you get is actually a `BaseController` and also even more specifically a more derived controller (e.g: `HomeController`, ...).

Comment: Your second solution works great on .NET 5, first is not.